# What's the best option to display images without changing their proportions?

Tags: android, image, gridview, tablelayout

i want to display some images from a content provider. However, i don't want to put them in GridView's squares but to keep their proportions, like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zeat30ysgq0771p/cameraroll-1343768439.055887.png

I want to define some height for a row and fill it with the images until reach a max width. Them i create a new row and start again.

What's the best way to doing this and keep good performance? TableLayouts with ImageViews inside each TableRow? TableLayouts with unique-row GridViews inside each TableRow? GridLayout? Make a custom view?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ImageView as wrap_content....So, as per your image size it is automatically scaled...